# Ambiguity: "premium-bonds" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Referring to [premium-bonds](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/premium-bonds). There are only 4 questions at the moment, but I'm just going to mention that "premium bonds" has two meanings:

- > A premium bond is a bond trading above its face value…

  Source: [Investopedia: Premium Bond](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/premiumbond.asp)
- > A Premium Bond is a lottery bond issued by the United Kingdom government since 1956.

  Source: [Wikipedia: Premium Bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premium_Bond)

This isn't really a problem at the moment, and I have no solution to this yet.

Comment: Making it more interesting, half of the existing questions have one usage, and half the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not convinced that the "Bond trading above its face value" usage is something worthy of a tag. We don't any questions tagged as "discount-bonds". I suspect that people asking the questions found the tag because of the previous usage for the UK scenario.

I propose renaming the tag "uk-premium-bonds" and removing it from the other two questions. [EDIT : I've now done this]